# How to check type of order notes in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to check the type of order notes in `woocommerce`?

I want to check the note is private_note or customer_note.

**Here is my code:**

```
//add_action('wp_insert_comment','hook_insert_func',100,2);
add_filter( 'comments_clauses','hook_insert_func',100,2);
function hook_insert_func($id, $comment){

    if($comment->comment_type!='order_note')
    return;

    if($comment->comment_type == 'order_note'){
            $mobile  = PWooSMS()->buyerMobile($comment->comment_post_ID);

            $data            = array();
            $data['type']    = 1;
            $data['mobile']  = "$mobile";
            $data['message'] = $comment->comment_content;
            $response = PWooSMS()->SendSMS( $data );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Based on the code I can assume but want to make sure that assumption is right.

Comment: @MarkTruitt I want to send sms when admin write a note for the customer, but I don't want to send sms when admin write the private note, it seems the order notes have a property `is_customer_note` but I don't know how to use it
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#1624-1680